# How to ignore the the app list when share file from one app to another app using xamarin android intent?

Tags: android-intent, xamarin.android

How can we ignore the app list when share files from one app to another app? I am using the below code to launch the supported app list when click share option. I want to list the few apps only from the list. For Ex: i want to restric watsapp, Gmail when share pdf files. Can anyone suggest your ideas to achieve this?

```
var pathFile = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            var absolutePath = pathFile.AbsolutePath;
            var m_documentMobiNames = shortName + ".pdf";
            var mobileFileName = Path.Combine(absolutePath, m_documentMobiNames);
            Context context = MainActivity.Active.BaseContext;
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
            sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, ""); 
            sendIntent.SetType("application/pdf");
            sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mobileFileName)); 
            if (sendIntent.ResolveActivity(context.PackageManager) != null)
            {
                context.StartActivity(sendIntent);

            }
```